# Is my likelihood function correct?

Tags: regression

$x_1, ... , x_n$ are known constants and $Y_1, ... , Y_n$ satisfy $Y_i = Bx_i + \epsilon_i$ where $\epsilon_i$ are independent, $N(0, \sigma^2)$, random variables.

I said my likelihood function is

$$\prod_{i = 1}^n\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left({-\frac{(x - Bx_i)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)$$

Is this correct

Comment: It cannot be correct because it includes an undefined symbol "$x$".  While you're pondering that, double-check the pdf for the standard normal distribution and notice the factor of $1/2$ in the exponent--that mustn't be overlooked, either.

Comment: @whuber I was thinking about that as I wrote it up. Would (inside the exponent) be $-\frac{-Bx_i}{\sigma}^2$? I know its defo to do with using the PDF for normal distribution and the comments on one of my previous questions: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47040/write-down-the-log-likelihood-function-for-this-model show me that this is $N(Bx_i, \sigma^2)$, is that correct? Oh yeah, that 1/2 was a silly mistake. Sorry.

Comment: You need some notation for the data: notice that the $x_i$ are *not* data.  Start with a dataset of *one* value and write down its likelihood in terms of the data value, $B$, $\sigma$, and $x_1$.  The rest is easy, because independence of the data implies the likelihood when $n\gt 1$ is the product of the likelihoods of the data.

Comment: What do you mean by "notation for data"? Incase it helps, I'm supposed to work out the MLE of $B$.

Comment: You need names for each of the numbers in the dataset whose likelihood you wish to write down.  You haven't even mentioned those data yet, which is why you're struggling.  (The $Y_i$ are *random variables,* not data values.)

Comment: Can YOU (personally) tell what the likelihood function should be from the information I have given you or have I therefore not written down everything needed to calculate it?

Comment: Yes, you have provided all the information needed to write a likelihood (assuming independent data), because you have specified the distributions.  But my writing it down won't help you achieve the understanding you seek: obviously you have seen likelihood expressions before, but now you're having to work out some details that weren't apparent to you when you read those expressions.  The best I can do for you is to help you focus your energies so you don't waste effort.

Comment: @whuber If I need to work out the MLE of $B$, then would the bit on the numerator of the exponent be $(B_i x_i)^2$? Oh, defo. I didn't want you to give me the answer lol. I was just making sure I hadn't missed out writing up some important information (meaning I didn't recognise it was important when I was doing it)

Comment: @whuber: I tried to help without spoiling everything.

Answer (score 2):

You have already seen that the $Y_i$'s are independent, with $Y_i\sim\mathrm{N}(Bx_i,\sigma^2)$, where the $x_i$'s are **known constants**. First of all, write down the expression of the densities:
$$
  f_{Y_i}(t) = (?) \, .
$$

That is easy. Just be careful. Now, in your problem you observe the values of the random variables $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$. You need to write the expression of their joint density. Remembering that they are independent, you have
$$
  f_{Y_1,\dots,Y_n}(t_1,\dots,t_n) = f_{Y_1}(t_1) \dots f_{Y_n}(t_n) = (?) \, .
$$
OK, almost there. Here comes the concept of likelihood. Let the observed values of $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ be $y_1,\dots,y_n$; these little $y_i$'s are your **data**. The likelihood of $B$ and $\sigma^2$, which you may denote by $L_{y_1,\dots,y_n}(B,\sigma^2)$ is just the expression of $f_{Y_1,\dots,Y_n}(y_1,\dots,y_n)$, which you should already know, seem as a function of $B$ and $\sigma^2$. So, just write it down:
$$
   L_{y_1,\dots,y_n}(B,\sigma^2) = f_{Y_1,\dots,Y_n}(y_1,\dots,y_n) = (?) \, .
$$